# htaccess rewrite is not working subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following code in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.html 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

the redirect is not working properly on subfolders. it works perfectly with root files.
it creates dots at the end of the subdirectory .html pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Make sure that you have enable rewrite module:

`sudo a2enmod rewrite`

- At the virtual hosts you have the allow override to all for your site:
  (/etc/apache2/sites-available/default)

```
 
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride ALL
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
```

- Make sure that your files have the right permissions 755 and the owner is the apache (www-data:www-data)
- Always remember to restart apache.